# how to calculate a byte value

Tags: hex, crc, packet, unknown-data, checksum

We are reversing the method of creating a byte array packet.

These values are obtained by serialport monitor from mediatek metamode usb port.The values of both packets are changed by changing the imei.

example imei : 534534324234239

```
 55 00 38 D0 40 01 34 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 C8 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0E 00 12 00 01 00 0E 00
 22 00 18 00 10 EF 01 00 01 00 0A 00 01 00 00 00
 00 00 35 54 43 23 24 43 32 F9 00 00 72
```

Packet2 is :

```
55 00 08 D0 00 FF 04 00 00 00 C2 75 C1
```

We have trouble making packet2, we know last "C1" hex is XOR and the rest are fixed values and do not change.We just do not know by what calculations the value of "C2" in packet 2 was obtained.

Comment: Please provide more details of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please provide a sample of multiple packets, ideally 100. That'll make it easier to infer algorithm

Comment: i find solution ,first need to reversed hex imei and need Addition byte by byte and output need to Addition with 31, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution ,first need to reverse imei array (without F in packet1) and need Addition byte by byte and output need to Addition with 31, thanks

Comment: That is super interesting. I think when looking for checksums I've always looked left to right, not right to left.